# simple vb code snippet

Tags: vb.net

whatd does following code do in VB?

```
 Convert.ToInt32(rmaValidationCode.ToCharArray().GetValue(0), 16) Mod 2) = 1
```

note :Private rmaValidationCode As String

Comment: -1 Squirrelly question with bad context etc. and an asker being a bad SO citizen with 5% acceptance...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vb Convert.ToInt32 syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564506/vb-convert-toint32-syntax)

Answer (score 1):

Takes first character of rmaValidationCode string, converts it to int from base 16 and checks if the resulting number is odd.